# How to use Reachability Objective-C class in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, network-programming

I need to get notified when connectivity changes during app usage. I have imported Reachability.h .m files to my Swift project, and bridged it by adding `#include "Reachability.h"`.

In Apple's Reachability example [project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) an observer is set up to get notified when connectivity changes. How can I set it up in Swift?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

There is no equivalent observer in Swift. Swift has property observers like `willSet` and `didSet`.

Comment: i did not understand your question

Comment: Have you used Reachability.h .m in Objective-C?

Comment: yes i used it in objective c

Comment: How do you use `Reachability` in Swift? How do you write `addObserver` line is Swift?

Comment: ok i give you that line

Comment: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)

Comment: and why you used objective c Reachability class when there is Reachability in swift

Comment: is it? where I can find?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74706/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-janos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please referred following link for Reachability in swift https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

For your add observer please use it like this

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)
```

Comment: how have you fixed `localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = in_addr_t(Int64(0xA9FE0000).bigEndian)` Integer literal overflows when stored into 'Int' issue? in Xcode 6.3?

Comment: may this link help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645798/does-swift-support-implicit-conversion

Comment: There was an update on https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift, it helped me :)