# implicit cast to primitive in swift

Tags: swift, casting, implicit-conversion

If I have a struct, I can implement `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` to implicitly create an instance of it from an integer literal.

```
struct MyStruct: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    let value: Int

    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}


let a: MyStruct = 1
```

Nice.

Is there a way to do the opposite i.e. implicitly convert from a `MyStruct` to an `Int`?

I know that I can implement an init method in an extension on `Int` to get explicit casting to work, like this:

```
extension Int {
    init(_ myStruct: MyStruct) {
        self = myStruct.value
    }
}


let b = Int(a)
```

But is there anything I can do to get this line to compile:

```
let c: Int = a
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645798/does-swift-support-implicit-conversion

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that in one line is to choose the value property:

```
let c: Int = a.value
```

Because you cannot overload the "=" you could check out that:

```
struct MyStruct: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    let value: Int

    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}


func += (inout left: Int, right: MyStruct) {
    left = right.value
}


let a: MyStruct = 1;
var c:Int = 0;
c += a
```

Otherwise you have to create your custom ExpressibleBy**Struct**Literal